# Joomla: Set up workflows so articles have to pass by an editor before publishing?

Tags: joomla, workflow, admin, backend

We need for articles to pass by an editor before getting published. Some pages need to pass by two different people. This is beyond the contributor/author/editor roles in the Joomla core, I think, because edits to existing pages need to be held for approval, during which time the original page needs to remain live.

Is this possible in Joomla 3.x?

Comment: Actually the new versioning system may help you but at this point I think you would need some custom code, such as a plugin to manage that.

Answer (score 0):

[An extension like this may help you](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/extensions-specific-non-sorted/7905?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo4OiJ3b3JrZmxvdyI7aToxO3M6OToid29ya2Zsb3dzIjt9)

and other options are also ther use 3rd party software like [processmaker](http://www.processmaker.com/) and integrate it in JOOMLA in iframe and [LDAP](http://docs.joomla.org/LDAP) to verify users.

open source version of processmaker is available and free to use

Comment: The first link in this answer no longer works, and since the link doesn't include enough information to identify what extension was being referred to, that part of the answer is now worthless.