# Content review workflow on Joomla! with K2 plugin installed

Tags: joomla, workflow, admin, backend

Got same needs as stated by Margie in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867884/joomla-set-up-workflows-so-articles-have-to-pass-by-an-editor-before-publishing)

> ...need for articles to pass by an editor before getting published. Some pages need to pass by two different people.

I'm using Joomla!2.5+K2 plugin. 
Can this config make it for this kind of worklow processing ?
If not, how should I modify the config to anable this ?

Comment: There are some extensions for workflow that support K2 I would look at those.  Also, anyway one step workflow is built into the core of Joomla, edit.state is the relevant permission. If the person has edit.state allowed they can publish and if not they cannot. Joomla also notifies designated groups when there is something ready for review if you enable that in the configuration.

Comment: Hi Elin, thaks a lot. Could you please name some of these K2-ready workflow extensions ?

Comment: I know Orbitto supports it.